# Over writing an array vs. Deleting and re-initializing it? Java

Tags: java, recursion, out-of-memory

is overwriting an array in java the same as deleting the elements and inserting new ones? I have a 50x50 array that stores floating point values. A method calculates new values and sends them to the same array that already has these values for overwriting the previous ones. This is a recurring procedure. After around 1500 iterations, stackoverflow error occurs. Would it be different if I set the array to null first before writing values to it?

Comment: Depends on your code.

Comment: 1500 iterations or 1500 recursions? Stack overflow exceptions occur when your stack allocation grows too large and crashes into the heap (a common issue with recursive functions that call themselves a lot)

Comment: khelwood already gave the perfect comment to this really but if you would just replace primitive values in the same array you shouldn't have any memory issues of any kind so there is something more going on in your code.

Comment: "Would it be different if I set the array to null first before writing values to it?" Have you tried it?

Comment: @Michael 1500 recursions.
Khelwood - sorry not at my system right now. but if it helps. The code/algo is something like:
P.S. the task does not decrease with each recursion and is meant to run for as long as I want. Will only stop if I manually hit stop compiling. 

code:
line 1: calculate initial float values
line 2 declartion of method 1 which calls method 2: method1(){
save each value in a 50x50 array
method2()
}
line3: declartion of method 2 which calls method 1 again: method2(){
calculate new float values
method1()
}

Comment: @UmairChaudhry Instead of putting code in a comment, please edit your question and put it there (much easier to read). Also much better if you can put the code from your original problem and it's an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @UmairChaudhry Provide further details as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.

Answer (score 0):

> The code is:

```
    float n = input.nextFloat();
    public static void calculate_initial_float_values(){

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){ 
      for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++){

      a[i][j] = i+j+n*n ; 
      } 
    }
      change_values();
  }

    public static void change_values(){
        n = rng.Random(9);
        calculate_initial_float_values(); 
  }
```